# How to calculate capital gain on gold coins in Canada?

Tags: canada, capital-gains-tax, gold

In case of purchasing multiple gold coins (assume same kind of coin) on several occasions, for the purpose of capital gains tax calculation upon resale -  does one have to calculate adjusted cost base to average out the cost (for "gold"), or can individual coin purchases be treated as separate securities altogether?

Comment: Do the coins have a serial number that can be used to differentiate them?

Comment: I have not bought them, yet, so don't know :). Assume Canadian Maple leaf 1 oz though.

Comment: Did some more research - assume no serial number, but would be curious to find out what difference this makes.